# Storing User Input in an Array or an Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, user-input, storing-data

this is a first time posting so forgive if the question is bad.

I have been messing around with GUI in netbeans and trying to get user input from a text field into an Array or an ArrayList. I am trying to temporarily store the user input for a customerName, address, date, number of outlets and number of zones and then display them in a TextArea as a list that is sorted by date.

The code I have tried just then is:

```
private void enterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


    List<List<String>> model = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
     ArrayList<Double> numOutlets = new ArrayList<Double>();

  nameField.selectAll();
  addressField.selectAll();
  outletField.selectAll();
  String customerName = nameField.getSelectedText();
  String address = addressField.getSelectedText(); 

  List<String> line = Arrays.asList(new String[]{customerName, address});
          model.add(line);

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          Display.append(String.format("Customer    Address"));
          for(List<String> input : model) {
              for (String item : input) {
                  Display.append(item);
                  if (input.indexOf(item) == input.size()-1) {
                      Display.append("\n");
                  } else {
                      Display.append("\t");


                  }
              }
          }





  /*Display.append(String.format(" " + installationNumber + "   " + customerName + "   " + address));

                nameField.setText("");
                addressField.setText("");
                zoneField.setText("");
                outletField.setText("");
                dateField.setText("");

     installationNumber++;
```

The main problems I have been having is storing the user inputs from the textfields into the arrays.

If you have another way i should go about it then that would also be awesome, I am relatively new to Java and I have really only done a few little programs

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Post your code and specify exactly what and where you are having the problem.

Comment: do you have a single textfield for the whole adress ?

Comment: Yeah i have got a single textfield for the whole address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, storing data in an Array or an ArrayList does not make much difference in a way you will iterate through the items. However, using the ArrayList looks cleaner because it groups related information (name and address of one customer) together.
I think a better approach is to create a model class to hold the data. Something like this:

```
private class Customer {
    private name;
    private address;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

Then in your code, you save information like below:

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

String customerName = nameField.getSelectedText();
String address = addressField.getSelectedText(); 
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setName(customerName); 
customer.setAddress(address);
customers.add(customer);
```

Now you can iterate through the customer list:

```
for(Customer input : customers) {
    Display.append(input.getName());
    Display.append("\t");
    Display.append(input.getAddress());
    Display.append("\n");
}
```

It is also easier if you want to display more information from customer (like telephone number, gender,...). What will the code look like in that case if you use array or ArrayList?

Comment: Thank you very much, that cleared it up for me it is all running well now, thanks!